# Lombok @NonNull Does Not Apply Check on Return Type

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, junit5

IDE: Intellij

I am using Lombok's NonNull annotation to automatically generate Null Pointer Checks and throw exceptions on Method Arguments and Return Types.

On writing Unit Tests, the 'null' method Arguments do throw the exception, but the null return types do not throw exceptions.

```
import lombok.NonNull;
public @NonNull String function( @NonNull String input) {
    return null;
}
```

The following Test fails:

```
@Test
public void 
whenReturnTypeIsNull_ThenIllegalArgumentExceptionIsThrown(){
    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, ()-> testClass.function() );
}
```

With the Message:

```
Expected java.lang.IllegalArgumentException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Lombok project* [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) clearly states that the `NonNull` annotation allows to generate boilerplate null-checks for constructor and method arguments:

> You can use @NonNull on the parameter of a method or constructor to have lombok generate a null-check statement for you.

Thus you should programatically check you return value invariants, including being non-null.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Hmm... I thought it would work on return type. I do hope they are able to add that feature in future. At the moment, i think the feature is slightly incomplete.

Comment: @DolphinJava Lombok author here: Lombok does not want to add runtime dependencies and lombok allows you to control the thrown exception as well as the message produced, which means using `Objects.requireNonNull` is not possible. Therefore, all return statements need to be split up into 3 statements (`return X;` becomes `T $foo = X; if ($foo == null) throw ...; return $foo;`), requiring type resolution, introducing braces, yadayada. Too complicated to be able to reliably do that.